# Set supported orientation for Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have a WP8 project originated from template "DirectX App (Windows Phone 8.0)". How do I set supported orientation (I want to make it landscape-only)? I have found file named "WMAppManifest.xml" in project folder, but it has no "orientation" option.

Comment: Mybe those links will help you: [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx), [two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/12/12/orientation-support-for-windows-phone-8.aspx), [three](http://www.catalinzima.com/2012/12/handling-orientation-in-a-windows-phone-8-game/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `performance` reasons, the option of automatic rotation is not available on `Windows Phone 8`, so we’re stuck with having to manually take care of everything: rotating stuff before we draw them, and processing input values to fit them to the new orientation. There are several things that we need to do in order to support other orientations besides the default Portrait one.

You can find more Reference here [Handling Orientation in a Windows Phone 8 game](http://www.catalinzima.com/2012/12/handling-orientation-in-a-windows-phone-8-game/)